# state value not change reactjs when axios get

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

When I used this code as an API in Python(Django) to return three characters from the username but unfortunately the value of the state does not change.

Django code:

```
class usertype(APIView):
def get(self,request,format=None):
    try:
        user=User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    except:
        raise ValueError('error')
    if not user.is_superuser:
        data={
            'usertype':user.username[:3],
        }
        return Response(data)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Reactjs code:

```
state={
usertype:'',
    }
gettype()
 {
  api.get('/').then(res=>{
   this.setState({usertype:res.data.usertype});
   });
 }
showDash()
 {
   switch(this.state.usertype){
      case "std":
          ///code
          break;
      case "thr":
          ///code
          break;
      default:
         ///code
        break; 
    }
}
```

All imports are correct and there are no problems with the library installation.
how can i fix this problem!

Comment: can you please share from where you are calling `gettype` and `showDash` function?

Comment: sorry, it's not so hard but i'm beginner . gettype function just changing state value and thats calling in componentDidMount

Comment: can you share where you are calling the showDash function?
i think it has something to do with showdash being called before state value is set

Comment: thosDash function just shows dashboard for each user and call in render function